# Serializar imagen en base64 con javascript pero compatible con .NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Tengo una base de datos postgres donde guardo imagenes en un campo tipo bytea. Cuando convierto una imagen a base 64 con C# y la serializo con NewtonSoft entonces la guarda y luego la consulto y la muestro perfecto. Sin embargo intentando hacer lo mismo con javascript como que la forma de serializar la imagen es diferente. Como logro que sea el mismo formato??. El código javascript que tengo es este:

```
carga.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (selectedFile) {
            
            let fileReader = new FileReader();
            
            let blob=new Blob([selectedFile]);

            fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            
            fileReader.onload = async(event) => {

                let data = event.target.result;

                console.log(btoa(data));
                let idNen= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('idNegocio'));

                var raw = JSON.stringify({
                    "Id": idNen[0].id,
                    "Data":btoa(data)
                });


                await crearImagen(raw);
            }
        } else {
            this.mostrarMensaje(`No se pudo reconocer la imagen. Por favor revise los datos`, `error`);
        }

    });



async function crearImagen(raw) {
    try {
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        efect.style.display = 'block';
        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${this.token}`);
        myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        
        var requestOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: myHeaders,
          body: raw,
          redirect: 'follow'
        };
        
       await fetch(`${this.url}/api/imagenes`, requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(result => 
            {
                console.log(result);
                this.mostrarMensaje(`Imagen registrada exitosamente!`, `success`);
            })
          .catch(error => console.log('error', error));  
    } catch (error) {
        this.mostrarMensaje(error, `error`);
    }
    modal.style.display = 'none';
        efect.style.display = 'none';
}
```

El código c# que funciona es este:

```
string ruta = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures\nod.png";

            var bites= File.ReadAllBytes(ruta);

            var base64=Convert.ToBase64String(bites);

            var anonimo = new {titulo="test",data=base64 };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(anonimo,Formatting.Indented);
```

El formato con .NET  del base64 en el json serializado  que funciona es este :

```
"data": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/ ......
```

y el formato que me crea javascript es algo como esto :

```
 "data": "ZGF0YTphcHBsaWNhdGlvbi9vY3RldC1zdHJlYW07YmFzZTY0LGlWQk9SdzBLR2dvQUF
```

Como ven es diferente y cuando consulto la imagen en ese formato la imagen no se muestra correctamente.

Comment: Hola! Podrías incluir en la pregunta, el código C# que serializa la imagen y la implementación del método crearImagen en el JS, por favor?

Comment: @Alfabravo Listo el código!

Comment: La generación del base64 [es la usada normalmente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325661/convert-an-image-selected-by-path-to-base64-string), parece estar bien. Creería entonces que algo pasa al serializar el JSON con newtonSoft. No conozco mucho de C# así que no sabría añadir algo más.

Comment: La serialización con NewtoSoft funciona perfectamente. La que no me funciona es la que hago con javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basandome en una respuesta que dieron en este enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534783/how-to-reconstruct-audio-blob-from-a-base64-encoded-string. Pude encontrar una solución a mi problema pues el  método readAsDataURL() del FileReader ya convierte la imagen a base64 sin embargo esta contiene unos headers que hay que remover para quedarse solo con la parte codificada. Yo removí los headers de la siguiente forma:

```
carga.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
    
            if (selectedFile) {
                
                let fileReader = new FileReader();
                
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
                
                fileReader.onload = async(event) => {
    
                    let data = event.target.result;
                    let BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
                    let base64Index = data.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
                    let base64 = data.substring(base64Index);
                    console.log(base64);
                    let idNen= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('idNegocio'));
    
                    var raw = JSON.stringify({
                        "Id": idNen[0].id,
                        "Data":base64
                    });
    
    
                    await crearImagen(raw);
                }
            } else {
                this.mostrarMensaje(`No se pudo reconocer la imagen. Por favor revise los datos`, `error`);
            }
    
        });
```

Con esto ya pude almacenar la imagen en la base de datos y utilizarla como las que guardo desde C#.